Can the Trinity doctrine be proved Biblically by the following verses? If not, why not?
Galatians 3:20, "Now a mediator is not a mediator of one, but God is one."
The person of the Father is God. (2 Peter 1:17.)
The person of the Son is God, (Titus 2:13 and at 2 Peter 1:1)
The person of the Holy Spirit is God. (Acts 5:3-4)
The three persons, (Father or God; Son or Christ or Lord; and Holy Spirit or Spirit) are listed together in a triadic pattern of unity and equality (John 14:26). Romans 8:11.
In summary, the doctrine of the trinity is not an "assumption." It is the normative systematic theology of God in Christianity and is based on the fact that the Bible is explicit in telling us that there is, was and forever will be only ONE God, AND the fact that the Bible identifies three (and only three) persons as God.

Would this be better on Christianity SX?  I would simply reply that (IMHO) the doctrine of the trinity is the only way to harmonize ALL the Biblical data.  I would also warn that there are at least three different and incompatible formulations of the trinity doctrine.  Two of these I would beg to differ with.

Yes it would but I have one major problem? I have been banned from posting there for one year about a month ago. I don't know if it can be appealed but it's not like I committed murder and some on there said it was a very harsh punishment. Now what?

Thanks Dottard. I appreciate you concern. They did not like the form of my answers because I answered like I do on other sites that I'm on. I was trying to accommodate Alex Balilo. I already know the answer and I don't ask a question that I don't already know the answer. I've been a Christian/Trinitarian for 63 years now. And again, thanks for your concern. Btw, I love and enjoy your answers. Keep up the good work.

Is this "using the bible" > "using only the bible" ? but then could Zeus have proved he had hypostatic unity in Olympus using only the Iliad? only to a degree... and then maybe an electron has moved by being looked at. "prove the Trinity"+"use only the bible" would remove the history-of-ideas from the hermeneutic. And there are places where the Son and Father are treated with but not the Spirit, which might need to be understood in context of a contemporary Graceo-Roman taboo on deifying mortals more than a later Arianite one. So please clarify this point about only

Tri-une God is found in the OT. For English readers Isaiah 48:16 has God speaking and has God sending God and God’s Spirit. But if you could read Hebrew you will find more nuanced examples like Isaiah 54:5 speaks of husbands and makers in the plural this doesn’t come out in the translated text. You also have NT passages where Jesus claims equality with God, that is only possible if one is God because God is unlike any other. And throughout the OT and NT you have examples of three that claim to be God either the Angel of the Lord (Jesus in the NT), the Father or the invisible God and the Spirit

Thanks for the encouragement.

Of related interest: Friends, we are not Christian! - Biblical Hermeneutics Meta Stack Exchange.

Systematic theology is off topic on this site.

My problem with this question is not with what it asks, but with how it's written. It presents references to four scriptures, but doesn't actually quote them. Even if it did, it would still be inadequate (e.g. 2 Peter 1:1 says "the righteousness of God and our Saviour Jesus Christ", which doesn't obviously mean "the Son is God". Similarly, Acts 5:3,4 don't say "the Holy Spirit is God".). As currently written, the question certainly doesn't present a strong case for the Trinity.

Actually the verses chosen are not mine. I used those verses as sort of "consensus" that most people would have used. I would not use any of them personally. In fact, I can prove the trinity teaching is Biblical by inductive/deductive reasoning. As far as not quoting the Scriptures I find it more productive for a person to look up the verses and read them for themselves. Personally, those verses presented are about weak as you can get.

A basic definition of the trinity might be: one God existing in three Persons.
You ask: Can Trinitarians prove the doctrine of the trinity by using the Bible only? Yes.
Let's use this definition for proof:

A proof is sufficient evidence or a sufficient argument for the truth
of a proposition. [1]

We have sufficient biblical evidence for the trinity based on the whole corpus of the bible.
Do we have sufficient biblical evidence for the trinity based only on the verses Matthew 28:19 and Matthew 3:16-17? Even as a trinitarian I must say "no".

Matthew 28:19 - Go therefore and make disciples of all the nations,
baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the
Holy Spirit,


Matthew 3:16-17 - When He had been baptized, Jesus came up immediately
from the water; and behold, the heavens were opened to Him, and He
saw the Spirit of God descending like a dove and alighting upon Him.
17 And suddenly a voice came from heaven, saying, “This is My beloved
Son, in whom I am well pleased.”

Both of these verses do not state necessary components for establishing the trinity. They do not explicitly state the following:

They are three distinct persons.
They are three in one.
These three are co-equal and co-eternal.
These three are all fully God.
They share the same divine essence.
They exist in a perfect unity.
They have distinct roles and personhood.
They are inseparable in their divine nature.

Conclusion: These two verses alone are not sufficient to fully prove the Trinity. Evidence for the Trinity is derived from scripture throughout the entire Bible. Nonetheless, these two verses are important components of the biblical evidence used to support the doctrine, however they cannot bear the full proof of the Trinity on their own.

“And we know that the Son of God has come and has given us understanding, so that we may know him who is true; and we are in him who is true, in his Son Jesus Christ. He is the true God and eternal life.”
‭‭1 John‬ ‭5‬:‭20‬ ‭there are plenty of verses pointing to Jesus and the Angel of the Lord in the OT as being God, directly or indirectly. Check out my comment above.

Good points, also Nihil's comments. Is not the problem of to whom this doctrine can be proven avoideded by the OP? To oneself, or to fellow believers in Jesus or to those who hate the Trinity doctrine? The scope is even too vast for the Christianity site. Even refined, the Q just leaves me shaking my head at the impossibility of answering it to satisfy others. How I came to be moved from hating that doctrine to believing it with joy is not so much 'proof' as evidence of being brought to spiritual life by God's revealing of scripture. This Q does not suit this site. +1

Please don't answer off topic questions.

Modalistic Monarchianism retains the monotheistic doctrine of the Old Testament teachings by the belief in different modes of manifestation rather than different persons.
It would teach that the only devine nature indwelling the Son of God was that of the Father Himself and since His fleshly body was begotten by Him it could technically be called His son (Luke 1:35 "for that reason the holy offspring shall be called the Son of God").
Thus when Jesus spoke of His humanity be it His flesh or voice or anything to do with His flesh and bone body He would call it the "Son of God.
But when He spoke of the activities of the Devinity acting through that body He would instead consistently use the words "Son of Man" because the creator became one of His creations when He begat His own fleshly temple for Himself  to indwell in a woman who was descended from Abraham, Isaac, Jacob and David as He had promised them.
The term "Holy Spirit" also was used consistently in God's interaction with human beings since in virtually all mention of the Holy Spirit in scripture there is a human body being acted upon by God's spirit.
So....all things in scripture that seem to prove Trinitarianism can also be reconciled by Modalistic Monarchianism (a.k.a. Oneness Pentecostalism).
And since this discussion started with mentioning Matthew 28:19 that includes one of the two commonly used baptismal formulas (the other being Acts 2:38) there's a hidden fact that sheds light on that debate which no organized Christian denomination seems to realize.
When Jesus was walking the earth during His fleshly ministry all baptism were performed only in His presence with Him standing by "witnessing" and thus it was not necessary to call upon the Name to invoke His presence since He was already standing right there.
The great revelation of the day of Pentecost was that by calling upon the Name they could invoke His presence as a "witness" to baptism once again.
